# The CLI for chat-bot conversation is not coming after running it as a docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile, chatbot

I have crated a chat-bot using python 3.6 and TensorFlow 1.15. And created the Command line utility for testing in local environment.

The command line utility works fine without docker as shown in the below image.
[image: screenshot of command line utility]

The problem arrived when i dockerized or containerized the application with dependencies.
The Command line utility is automatically closing after running the docker image.

The dockerfile for the application as below.

```
FROM python:3.6-buster
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./req.txt ./
RUN pip install -r req.txt
COPY ./ ./
RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt
CMD ["python","botui.py"]
```

And after running the docker image it automatically shuts down the Command line utility.

[image: screenshot after running the application in docker env.]

Please help me in finding the solution.
should i need to add something in dockerfile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dockerfile seems fine.
for the interactive mode for your chatbot conversation you need to add "-i" flag in your docker run command.

```
docker run -i <image_name>
```